# PySpark when and loop - best practice?

Tags: python, pyspark

The code below generates a spark dataframe, creates a new feature called 'size' based on information in feature group, x and y. Apart from group the conditions is similar. A loop would be the go-to solution in 'normal' python - but what is best practice in PySpark for this?

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import random
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql.functions import col, when

# Generate the data using pandas
num_observations = 1000
groups = ['A', 'B', 'C']

df_pandas = pd.DataFrame({
    'id': range(1, num_observations + 1),
    'x': np.random.normal(loc=400, scale=25, size=num_observations).astype(int),
    'y': np.random.normal(loc=40, scale=10, size=num_observations).astype(int),
    'group' : [lst[random.randrange(len(lst))] for i in range(num_observations)]
})

# Create SparkSession
spark = SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()

# Convert pandas DataFrame to PySpark DataFrame
df_spark = spark.createDataFrame(df_pandas)


df_spark.withColumn('size', F.when((col('group')=='A') & ((col('x') < 100) | (col('y') < 10)), 'Category_1')
                    .when((col('group')=='A') & (col('x') >= 100) & (col('x') < 400) & (col('y') >= 10) & (col('y') < 40), 'Category_2')
                    .when((col('group')=='A') & (col('x') >= 400) | (col('y') >= 40), 'Category_3')
                    
                    .when((col('group')=='B') & ((col('x') < 100) | (col('y') < 10)), 'Category_1')
                    .when((col('group')=='B') & (col('x') >= 100) & (col('x') < 400) & (col('y') >= 10) & (col('y') < 40), 'Category_2')
                    .when((col('group')=='B') & (col('x') >= 400) | (col('y') >= 40), 'Category_3')
                    
                    .when((col('group')=='C') & ((col('x') < 100) | (col('y') < 10)), 'Category_1')
                    .when((col('group')=='C') & (col('x') >= 100) & (col('x') < 400) & (col('y') >= 10) & (col('y') < 40), 'Category_2')
                    .when((col('group')=='C') & (col('x') >= 400) | (col('y') >= 40), 'Category_3')
                   )



# Show the updated DataFrame
df_spark.toPandas()
```

Comment: How are you thinking of using a loop on PySpark dataframe?

Comment: does this only involve `when().otherwise()` statements? you could just use `reduce()` to create that and pass it to the `withColumn()`. btw, in your sample problem, it looks like you could just use `F.when((col('group').isin("A", "B", "C") & ..., 'Category_1')`.

Comment: I was thinking what is the way to go here, is it a loop inside the when clause or is it another approach? Happy to learn more about best practices when it comes to PySpark.

Comment: IMO, there's no harm in doing a list comprehension given it will "create" the `when().otherwise()` conditions that will get executed.

Comment: @samkart so, inside the withColumn, do a list comprehension on the when().otherwise(). Is there any other valid approaches?